# multilingual ontologies

Tags: ontology, owl

I'm new to Protege OWL 4 and confused about multilingual ontologies. I want to quickly start a non-english OWL  based on an English one. I have three questions:

1. Which plugins to use? there is an OntoLing http://ainlp.info.uniroma2.it/software/OntoLing/UserManual.html#LinguisticEnrichment
2. If mapping, how to do it, is there a tutorial?
3. Labels of the annotation property don't have the language I want

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would usually approach this by using the original english ontology and add annotion labels. In **Protégé 4**, you can add custom languages to the labels by simply entering the desired value directly into the `Lang` field, in the **Add Annotation Dialog** (see screenshot).

[image]